# How to parse json newline delimited in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, aws-sdk

I am writing an Angular 2 app (built with angular cli), and trying to use AWS Polly text-to-speech API.

According to the API you can request audio output as well as "Speech Marks" which can describe word timing, visemes, etc.  The audio is delivered as "mp3" format, and the speech marks as "application/x-json-stream", which I understand as a "new line" delimited JSON.  It cannot be parsed with JSON.parse() due to the new lines.  I have yet been unable to read/parse this data.  I have looked at several libs that are for "json streaming" but they are all built for node.js and won't work with Angular 2.  My code is as follows...

```
onClick() {
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'xxxxx';
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'yyyyy';
let polly = new AWS.Polly();

var params = {
  OutputFormat: 'json',
  Text: 'Hello world', 
  VoiceId: 'Joanna',
  SpeechMarkTypes:['viseme']
};

polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(data.AudioStream);
    var arrayBuffer = uInt8Array.buffer;
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

   this.audio.src = url;
   this.audio.play(); // works fine

   // speech marks info displays "application/x-json-stream"
   console.log(data.ContentType); 
  }
});
```

Strangely enough Chrome browser knows how to read this data and displays it in the response.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I saved the file so I could then read it line by line, accessing the JSON objects when I need to highlight words being read. Mind you this is probably not the most effective way, but an easy way to move on and get working on the fun stuff.

I am trying out different ways to work with Polly, will update answer if I find a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson-parse

That worked for me.

But I can't play audio, I tried your code it says

DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.